# How to make flutter desktop app goes fullscreen when move to top of the screen

Tags: flutter, fullscreen, flutter-desktop

When I move my app to the top of the screen
[image]

I want to make it look like this and then file explorer goes fullscreen
[image]

Comment: Which OS system/distrubution is this?

Comment: this is windows 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [windows_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/window_manager) package. add this code to your main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:window_manager/window_manager.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Must add this line.
  await windowManager.ensureInitialized();

  // Use it only after calling `hiddenWindowAtLaunch`
  windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow().then((_) async{
    // Hide window title bar
    await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden);
    await windowManager.setSize(Size(800, 600));
    await windowManager.center();
    await windowManager.show();
    await windowManager.setSkipTaskbar(false);
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Just add **WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW** to window_class in win32_window.cpp